# Row-wise summation errors

Tags: r

I have "wide-format" data that begins:

```
id var_1 var_2 var_3...
1  NaN   0     1
2  2     NaN   3
3  1     4     NaN
.
.
.
```

The entire data-set is thousands of observations and hundreds of variables. I'm trying to filter for observations that have a value of exactly 1 in any of var_1 through var_12.

My attempt

```
library(package = dplyr)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(my_obs = select(var_1:var_12) %>%
           apply(MARGIN = 1, 
                 FUN = function(x) any(x == 1,
                                       na.rm = TRUE)) == TRUE) %>%
  filter(my_obs == 1)
```

generated the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots):

no applicable method for "select_" applied to an object of class
c("double", "numeric")
```

Comment: Do you want the rows which contains the value of 1 in any variable or those that have a row sum of 1 across the 12 variables?

Comment: @shayaa rows which contain the value of 1 in any variable

Comment: Think you might want `apply(data[,1:12], 1, function(x) any(x==1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `rowSums` inside the `mutate` call

```
data %>% 
    mutate(special_sum = rowSums(.[grep("var_\\d+", names(.))], na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    filter(special_sum >=1)
```

If we don't want to create the `special_sum`, then this can be done within `filter` too

```
data %>%
     filter(rowSums(.[grep("var_\\d+", names(.))], na.rm = TRUE)>=1)
```